# How to configure Spring-Weflux WebSocket application to use WSS instead of WS

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I have a Spring-Webflux server which runs Netty.
Currently, clients connect via `ws`, but I need for them to connect via `wss`.

How to configure it to accept ONLY `wss`?